# Notepad++ shortcuts don't work with custom keyboard

Tags: notepad++, keyboard-layout

I use a custom dvorak keyboard layout that I made in the Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator. It's basically Dvorak, but I have it mapped so that when I press ctrl, all the keys get remapped to their Qwerty counterparts, so that keyboard shortcuts work from muscle memory.

Whenever I use notepad++ in this keyboard mode, keyboard shortcuts don't work as expected. As far as I can tell, the program inserts an extra character whenever I do something:

It reads <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+
<kbd>a</kbd> as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd> (which highlights all the text and then instantly replaces it with the letter `a`)

It reads <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+
<kbd>z</kbd> as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>, <kbd>z</kbd> (which undoes my change and then throws a `z` in its place)

And yes, I have confirmed that this only happens with the custom keyboard that I made.

Is there a way that I could fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because these keys are already mapped in notepad++ and it causes a conflict.

To get a workaround, simply remap the key shortcuts in notepad++:
`Settings -> Shortcut Mapper` for example `ctrl` + `a` to `ctrl` + `shift` + `a`

You will probably have these kind of conflicts in other programs as well, so I suggest finding another key instead of `ctrl` for remapping to QUERTY.